# Is reputation gained over the daily maximum lost?

Tags: support, reputation

So, say you gain 200 rep through some answers, questions and so on. And at the end of the day, you the most interesting answer ever and get another 20 upvotes for it, because it's just that brilliant.

This reputation won't be awarded. But is it lost? So will you never be rewarded for having the most groundbreaking question in the history of stackexchange?

If so, I think that's quite unfair...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As covered by the FAQ:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit). Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate reputation.
>
> https://german.stackexchange.com/faq

This is a reputation **cap**. That means that, yes, any additional reputation is lost.

It's not really unfair, it ensures that you need to show continual positive involvement in the community to gain more reputation, which translates into more power for you. Achieving Skeet status with a single fluke answer would be really unfair to those steadily investing time, but for whatever reason aren't upvoted as much.

Answer (score 1):

Decezes answer is true but incomplete.

The part of your question about

> having the most groundbreaking question in the history of stackexchange?

needs an answer. There is no badge 'Groundbreaker' but

- Good Answer: (silver) Answer score of 25 or more
- Great Answer: (gold) Answer score of 100 or more
- Guru: (silver) Accepted answer and score of 40 or more
- Nice Answer: (bronze) Answer score of 10 or more

are still awarded, and similar for questions, too.